# what are the pros and cons of using apache workers when deploying Django in production?

Tags: django, windows, apache

I've been looking at all the various ways to deploy a django project in a windows enviroment, and I came up with an interesting method - I'm now asking if this is a smart way to do it...

step 1. Run the django server via cmd `python manage.py runserver 8000`

step 2. Point an Apache worker to direct incomming traffic to Django

I won't pretend to be a networking master, but as long as Apache is the only thing outward facing and able to handle all the security....how insecure can this way be?
I can't help but feel like this is *cheesing* it somehow....
but I'd love to hear any optinions on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the [`manage.py runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver) in production. To quote the documentation:

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone
> through security audits or performance tests. (And that’s how it’s
> gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web
> servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production
> environment is outside the scope of Django.)

Just install a production-ready WSGI server like [`gunicorn`](https://gunicorn.org/) and use that instead of `runserver`. And make sure your settings are production ready (espcecially setting `DEBUG = False`).